# Powershell - Get-Date.AddDays how to get desired format

Tags: powershell

I have velow script

```
       $AddDays = Read-Host "How long user will be active (: in Days) "
       $DateInFuture = (Get-date).AddDays($AddDays).ToString('yyyy-mm-dd')
```

I want to add days to current date but instead i got sth like this ..

"2020-57-18"

And lets say today is "2020-04-18" and I added 5 days... 
How to add days with this format ? yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I dont get that when i run it. I get `2020-09-18`. I literally copy and pasted it into Powershell and it works fine.

Comment: me too .. i read this method should work , but its not .... weird ..

Comment: close powershell open it again.. copy and paste it from this document and tell me if its still wrong.

Comment: Still wrong . Today we have 2020-04-13, i just want to add five days so it should be 2020-04-18 but i got 2020-12-16 instead ..

Comment: Seems toString Method is not adding days correctly

Comment: Erick is right i didnt even notice the lowercase m.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the format using inside the ToString, `mm` represents minutes and `MM` represents months

```
$AddDays = Read-Host "How long user will be active (: in Days) "
$DateInFuture = (Get-date).AddDays($AddDays).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

This get's the desired output of `2020-04-18`

Comment: Output as string means you can't fully utilize this unless you convert it again to date

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$AddDays = Read-Host "How long user will be active (: in Days) "
$DateInFuture = (Get-Date).AddDays($AddDays) | Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
```